# showing apple maps with route navigation using siri in iphone programming

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, maps, uinavigationcontroller

I am showing apple maps with directions from start and end destination.I want it to open and start siri when user opens the map with the route.For some reason its opening the url successfully but not opening the siri to guide the user.

Code used for it is as shown below:

```
NSString* versionNum = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
     NSString *nativeMapScheme = @"maps.apple.com";
     if ([versionNum compare:@"6.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
     nativeMapScheme = @"maps.google.com";

     NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://%@/maps?daddr=%@&saddr=%f,%f",nativeMapScheme,[description stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],mylat, mylon];
     NSLog(@"Location - %@",url);

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```